# Building boost for Android

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk

I searched for Tutorials to build boost for Android. I found [this one](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2011/05/tips-tricks-building-boost-with-ndk-r5/). It seems to be THE Tutorial for it, cause all buildscripts I found (i.e. [this one](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android)) build on that.

It does not work for me. However I try to get it work, it does not. It's depressing already.

First thing is that there is an error telling me:

```
    Der Befehl ".." ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

Which is german for: could not find command ".."

I have no clue where that is coming from. It appears 4 time in a row.

Additionally to this Errors, I got this errors:

```
    cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-mthreads"
```

I found a solution for that here:
[unrecognized command line option while compiling boost for android on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274430/unrecognized-command-line-option-while-compiling-boost-for-android-on-cygwin)

Now I still have the ".."-Error and:

```
    Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    Performing configuration checks

        - 32-bit                   : yes
        - x86                      : no
        - power                    : no
        - arm                      : yes
    error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_context_sources
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <architecture>arm <binary-
    format>elf <toolset>gcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <architecture>arm <binary-
    format>elf <toolset>qcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>aapcs <architecture>arm <binary-
    format>elf
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-
    format>elf <toolset>gcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-
    format>elf <toolset>qcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>o32 <architecture>mips1 <binary-
    format>elf
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf <toolset>gcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf <toolset>qcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf <toolset>gcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf <toolset>qcc
            not matched
        next alternative: required properties: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architec
    ture>power <binary-format>elf
            not matched
```

Where I have no clue, what that could mean. And thats not everything.

[Here the whole output](http://pastebin.com/3XYBwvGV)

What do I do wrong?

Comment: you are not building with android ndk probably

Answer (score 0):

The include and library path details mentioned in user configuration DOESNOT match with the NDK PATH

plz check the following include path and update it as per the NDK path

-I$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include

-I$(ANDROID_NDK)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi/include

Once you update this path, you will not get the errors.